# Adding links in timeline view in a swift playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground, xcplayground

I've made a sample swift playground. [image]
I've added few playground pages and tried to give link using markups as given in docs but timeline view does not show any markups/Links.

How do I add links here and is there a way to navigate to next playground page on pressing a button event?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Playground** is created for getting familiar with the swift language. It is more language specific rather than Xcode oriented.

To navigate from one page to another you should instead start a new project and try to use **segues** for the purpose. Hope this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) will help you.

Comment: This won't work for playground right? I've been told this is useless but I wanted to design a swift playground to depict a story kind of thing that's why playgrounds was chosen

Comment: I'm afraid, it might not possible on playground, you have to create a separate new project for that. But you could definitely make look as simple as possible to depict playground.

Comment: But the way we navigate using markup can we just integrate that to a button?

Comment: No you can't, it works well on web pages but mobile applications follow some proceedures in switching pages, you have segue as only option.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I clicked on Editor -> Show rendered markup, now only if there were a way to navigate on clicking a button?

Comment: The markup is for showing rendered documentation in the *source editor*, not for the timeline view / live view. If you enabled show rendered markup, then the comment line //: [Next](@next) will be rendered as a clickable link in source editor.